# How to include a mat-card inside another mat-card. Output does not align

Tags: css, angularjs, sass, angular-material

I want to be able to include the test-card inside the mat-grid-tile. The test-card would supposedly contain a doughnut chart that would be the result of whatever computation the mat-tab will show. My problem is that the chart (test-card) does not align. I'm new to UI development, so please bear with me.

**html sample**

```
<mat-card class="sample-title">Test</mat-card>
    <mat-grid-list cols="4" rowHeight="280px">
      <mat-grid-tile colspan="3">
        <mat-card class = "card-class">
        <mat-tab-group>
          <mat-tab label="First">
            <mat-card>Content 1 </mat-card>
          </mat-tab>
          <mat-tab label="Second">
            <mat-card>Content 2</mat-card>
          </mat-tab>
          <mat-tab label="Third">
            <mat-card>Content 3</mat-card>
          </mat-tab>
          </mat-tab-group>
        </mat-card>
        <mat-card class="test-card">Test</mat-card>
      </mat-grid-tile>
    </mat-grid-list>
```

**css sample**

```
.sample-title {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "GT-Walsheim-Pro-Bold";
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
  border-top: 3px solid #175fab;
  border-radius: 0px;
  width: 700px;
  height: 15px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  right: 0;
}

.card-class {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "GT-Walsheim-Pro-Bold";
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 0px;
  width: 1500px;
  /* max-height: 400px; */
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: -120px;
  overflow: auto;
  right: 0;
}
```

Comment: You should be aware that placing a card inside another card is against material design "rules". An elevated item should never contain elevated items. A card is a fairly specific UX pattern - not a general purpose layout or style container. It would typically never have a tab container or other complex controls.

Comment: Thank you. I will take note of this. Not really a UI/UX person, so I guess I'll have to research more about material design "rules".